# Can't open upgrades menu in MvM

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I was playing on the Rottenburg map and after losing a couple waves, I tried to open the upgrade menu and couldn't. I would walk up to it and nothing appeared.

This happened to me a couple times and both times the only way to fix it was leaving the game. I've tried to join spectate and then click random but that didn't work

How can you fix this bug without having to leave the game?

Comment: Which upgrade menu were you using? The one near your spawn or the bots spawn? Did you try both?

Comment: @Studoku I just did the one by my spawn. No I didn't try both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/1/618457398964789187/) Steam community thread, it's possible to fix this bug by pressing the "inspect" key (<kbd>F</kbd> key by default), closing the box that appears and walking up to the upgrades bench again.

Comment: A class change/change back also works sometimes.